# How to use MonadRandom?

Tags: haskell

Can someone provide "for-dummies" example of how to use `MonadRandom'?

Currently I have code that does stuff like passing around the generator variable, all the way from the main function:

```
 main = do
     g <- getStdGen
     r <- myFunc g
     putStrLn "Result is : " ++ show r

 --my complicated func
 myFunc g x y z = afunc g x y z
 afunc g x y z = bfunc g x y
 bfunc g x y = cfunc g x
 cfunc g x = ret where
       (ret, _ ) = randomR (0.0, 1.0) g
```

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basically all the extra `g` parameters can just be dropped. You then get random numbers using the functions from [Control.Monad.Random](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.6/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html) (such as `getRandomR`). Here is your example (I added some args to make it compile):

```
import Control.Monad.Random

main = do
    g <- getStdGen
    let r = evalRand (myFunc 1 2 3) g :: Double
    -- or use runRand if you want to do more random stuff:
    -- let (r,g') = runRand (myFunc 1 2 3) g :: (Double,StdGen)
    putStrLn $ "Result is : " ++ show r

--my complicated func
myFunc x y z = afunc x y z
afunc x y z = bfunc x y
bfunc x y = cfunc x
cfunc x = do
    ret <- getRandomR (0.0,1.0)
    return ret
```

Comment: I think you have `runRand` and `evalRand` mixed up!

Comment: Not sure how that happened, since I ran the code :) Fixed now.

Comment: Of course, `myFunc`, `aFunc`, `bFunc`, and `cFunc` are now monadic.  They return values wrapped in the `Rand` monad, which have to be extracted with `>>=` (or `<-` in a `do`), and created with `return`.

Comment: Hm... isn't that kind of bad that they are monadic? I mean - i can't just use them from anywhere now, can I? I must use them from monads only?

Comment: No, you can use them from anywhere. You just need to use `evalRand` or `runRand` with a `RandGen` argument. Basically, you've changed from having to pass the argument around explicitly to getting that 'for free', but working inside a monad. It's also harder to make mistakes this way (like forgetting to pass on the second argument returned by `randomR`).

Comment: Remember, monadic doesn't imply the `IO` monad.  In this case, we're talking about the `Rand` monad.  It makes sure that the generator is threaded through your code correctly, so you don't inadvertently create two random numbers from the same state of the generator (which would generate two identical so-called random numbers).  In your example, you are discarding the new generator.  If you wanted to create a second random number, you might be tempted to use `g` again, but that would be incorrect.

Comment: So.. if my `cfunc` returns a modan, what should the `bfunc` be returning? Then `myFunc` is not going to return a `Double`?

Comment: Also, is it possible to replace `do
    ret <- getRandomR (0.0,1.0)
    return ret` with just one expression? Would `= getRandomR (0.0, 1.0)` work?

Comment: I'm getting `Couldn't match expected type 'Double' with actual type 'm0 a0'` in my `cfunc` when I put a type signature of `Integer->Double` on it.

Comment: The type signature for `cfunc` will be `MonadRandom m => Integer -> m Double`, since it's monadic. For your previous question, yes, `do x <- a; return x` is equivalent to just `a`. You can find out what the type signatures are by loading the code in GHCi and using the command `:t cfunc`. It will give you what GHC has figured out, which will be the most general version.

Comment: Thanks! I've posted my complete source which I'm trying to convert: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287546/how-to-refactor-code-to-use-monadrandom

Answer (score 10):

You just run something in the `RandT` monad transformer with `runRandT` or `evalRandT`, and for the pure `Rand` monad, with `runRand` or `evalRand`:

```
main = do
  g <- getStdGen
  r = evalRand twoEliteNumbers g
  putStrLn $ "Result is: " ++ show r

twoEliteNumbers :: (RandomGen g) => Rand g (Double, Double)
twoEliteNumbers = do
  -- You can call other functions in the Rand monad
  number1 <- eliteNumber
  number2 <- eliteNumber
  return $ (number1, number2)

eliteNumber :: (RandomGen g) => Rand g Double
eliteNumber = do
  -- When you need random numbers, just call the getRandom* functions
  randomNumber <- getRandomR (0.0, 1.0)
  return $ randomNumber * 1337
```

Comment: Also... what would happen if I called `func` not from main?

Comment: `do` doesn't mean that you use the `IO` monad. I'm using the `Rand` monad here.

Comment: `func` can be called from any other function in the `Rand` monad. I'll update with an example.