# How to refactor code to use MonadRandom

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use `MonadRandom`. I put it into `randomPref` function, but the whole thing brows up afterwards! Any tips are appreciated.

```
module AgentGenerator where

import System.Random
import Data.Hashable
import Control.Monad.Random

import System.Environment

-- Generate agents and write to a file
-- 'fname' - output filename
-- 's' - number of agent sets
-- 'n' - number of agents in a set
-- 'x' - number of preferences per agent
generate fname s n x = do
    writeFile fname $ show $ generateAgentSets s n x

-- Agent type: Name, List of preferences
data Agent = Agent String [Double] deriving Show
type AgentSet = [Agent]

-- Generate 's' sets of 'n' agents each, with 'x' preferences each
generateAgentSets:: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [AgentSet]
generateAgentSets s n x  = [generateAgents n x | i <- [1..s] ]

-- Generate n agents with 'x' preferences each
generateAgents:: Integer -> Integer -> AgentSet
generateAgents n x = [createAgent (show i) x | i <- [1..n]]

-- Create agent 'name' with 'x' preferences
createAgent:: String -> Integer -> Agent
createAgent name x = Agent name prefs where
    prefs = [ randomPref (i + hashed) | i <- [1..x] ]  where
        hashed = fromIntegral ( hash name )

-- Generate single random value between [0, 1] based on the seed
-- TODO: Get rid of the seed thing and use MonadRandom instead
randomPref :: (RandomGen g) => Integer -> Rand g [Double]
randomPref seed = getRandomR (0.0, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've defined `Agent` as

```
data Agent = Agent String [Double]
```

But in `createAgent`, you are trying to construct an `Agent` using the types

```
Agent String [Rand g [Double]]
```

Another type error is that in `randomPref`, the signature says that you are generating a list of random doubles, but you only generate one double. I'm also not 100% sure how the function should work, given that you never use the seed value anywhere. You either want to return a `Rand` monad or take a seed value and use that to generate a plain double. Having both doesn't really make sense.

Here's a version that uses a seed, and returns a plain double

```
randomPref :: Integer -> Double
randomPref seed = evalRand (getRandomR (0.0, 1.0)) g where
    g = mkStdGen (fromIntegral seed)
```

I've used `mkStdGen` from `System.Random` here as an example, but you might want to replace it with some other instance of `RandomGen`.

However, the above is a pretty questionable use of `MonadRandom` and unless it's really important to generate each agent with a specific seed, it's probably more logical to implement `randomPref` like this

```
randomPref :: RandomGen g => Rand g Double
randomPref = getRandomR (0.0, 1.0)
```

Now we don't take in a seed value, we just declare that `randomPref` is a random double. However, you can't just use a random double like it was a regular double, so we need to change the other functions too. First, `createAgent`

```
createAgent:: RandomGen g => String -> Int -> Rand g Agent
createAgent name x = Agent name <$> prefs where
    prefs = replicateM x randomPref
```

We change the signature to reflect the fact that we are actually returning a random `Agent`. The `<$>` operator is from the module `Control.Applicative` and it is used to apply a function expecting a plain value to a `Rand` value. This is just a nicer way to write `fmap (Agent name) prefs`.

`prefs` is defined in terms of `replicateM` (from the module Control.Monad), which replicates a monadic value x times, so you get x random prefs. On another note, I've changed all the functions to use `Int` values instead of `Integers`. Unless you really want to generate billions of agents, this makes the code a lot faster, and many standard library functions (like `replicateM`) only accept machine ints.

```
generateAgents:: RandomGen g => Int -> Int -> Rand g AgentSet
generateAgents n x = mapM (\i -> createAgent (show i) x) [1..n]
```

`generateAgents` is changed in a similar way. We note in the signature that we are returning a random `AgentSet`, and change the list comprehension into `mapM`. `mapM` is like the standard `map` function, except that is works with functions that return monadic values (such as `Rand`).

```
generateAgentSets:: RandomGen g => Int -> Int -> Int -> Rand g [AgentSet]
generateAgentSets s n x  = replicateM s (generateAgents n x)
```

`generateAgentSets` follows the same routine. We've replaced the list comprehension with `replicateM` to generate s instances of random agent sets.

The biggest change is required in the `generate` function

```
generate :: RandomGen g => FilePath -> Int -> Int -> Int -> g -> IO ()
generate fname s n x g = do
    let randomSets = generateAgentSets s n x
        agentSets  = evalRand randomSets g
    writeFile fname $ show agentSets
```

We need to pass in a random number generator, which is then used with `evalRand` to turn the `Rand AgentSet` values into plain `AgentSet` values that can then be written to disk.

To get a better understanding why we need `fmap`/`<$>` and functions such as `mapM` and `replicateM` instead of plain old list comprehensions, you might want to read [Chapter 11](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#functors-redux) and [Chapter 12](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#getting-our-feet-wet-with-maybe) from [Learn you a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: Thanks, you were right my `randomPref` should not return a list - I just found this type signature `Rand g [Double]` somewhere and used it unwittingly. And the `seed` is the remains of the old code - that did not use `MonadRandom` - in fact, everything except `randomPref` is the code that does not use `MonadRandom` - because I just gave up after trying to figure out how to use the damn thing! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: When I try to use `generate "out.txt" 2 10 3 getStdGen` from console I get `No instance for (RandomGen (IO StdGen))` error :-(

Comment: getStdGen returns a monadic value, so you need to do `getStdGen >>= generate "out.txt" 2 10 3`, or alternatively, you can use `generate "out.txt" 2 10 3 (newStdGen seed)`. The difference is that `getStdGen` returns the global, shared random generator and `newStdGen` creates a new random generator based on a seed value.

Comment: Thanks, but if I try `newStdGen 10` it complains that `newStdGen` should take no arguments...

Comment: Ah sorry, I was going by memory. The function I meant was `mkStdGen seed`.

Comment: Woot, this also worked: `a <- newStdGen; generate "out.txt" 2 3 1 a`

Comment: But why can't I call other functions the same way, e.g. I get an error if I try this from console: `let a = newStdGen >>= evalRand(createAgent 1)`

Comment: Oh nevermind! I got it: `g<-newStdGen; let a = evalRand(createAgent 1) g`