# picking a random element from a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So in a project of my I have a constant function that returns an array :

```
import System.Random

giveList :: [Int]
giveList = [8,9,4,5,2]
```

and I would like to randomly select an element from that list like this:

```
seed::Int
seed = 40

generator = mkStdGen seed

giveRandomElement :: Int
giveRandomElement = giveList !! rand where
    n = length tetrominoes
    (rand,generator) = randomR (0,(n-1)) generator
```

However, this does not compile because of the generator, I would like to keep the generator as a global variable so I don't have to keep giving it to functions.
I also don't want to deal with IO wrappers, so in what way can I do this ?

Thx for the help :-)

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Edited) How to get random number in Haskell without IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041993/edited-how-to-get-random-number-in-haskell-without-io)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A working code example

```
import System.Random

seed::Int
seed = 40

giveList :: [Int]
giveList = [8,9,4,5,2]

generator = mkStdGen seed

giveRandomElement :: Int
giveRandomElement = giveList !! rand where
  n = length giveList
  (rand, _) = randomR (0,(n-1)) generator
```

But that probably doesn't do, what you want.

`giveRandomElement` will always yield the same result. It is a pure function without any inputs, so what should it do? It can only be constant.

You either need to use `IO` or you need to thread your generator through your code and keep track of it somewhere.

The compiler error you got:

```
test.hs:14:23: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘g0’ arising from a use of ‘randomR’
      prevents the constraint ‘(RandomGen g0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include generator :: g0 (bound at test.hs:14:10)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘g0’ should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        instance RandomGen StdGen -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
    • In the expression: randomR (0, (n - 1)) generator
      In a pattern binding:
        (rand, generator) = randomR (0, (n - 1)) generator
      In an equation for ‘giveRandomElement’:
          giveRandomElement
            = giveList !! rand
            where
                n = length giveList
                (rand, generator) = randomR (0, (n - 1)) generator
   |
14 |   (rand, generator) = randomR (0,(n-1)) generator
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

was because you defined the symbol `generator` in `giveRandomElement` in terms
of it self and so the compiler couldn't deduce its type. (The top level declaration `generator` wasn't used in that case, because `(rand, generator) =` already shadowed the symbol after the equal sign.

Answer (score 8):

> I would like to keep the generator as a global variable so I don't have to keep giving it to functions. I also don't want to deal with IO wrappers, so in what way can I do this ?

Sorry, a function `giveRandomElement :: Int` that returns a different random number every time you call it **isn't [referentially transparent](https://wiki.haskell.org/Referential_transparency)**, so Haskell's purity does *not* allow you to do what you'd like.

I think working with random values is a great opportunity to learn about monads. [MonadRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266765/how-to-use-monadrandom) has a very flexible interface for writing functions whose results are random:

```hs
die :: (MonadRandom m) => m Int
die = getRandomR (1, 6)

rollDice :: (MonadRandom m) => m (Int, Int)
rollDice = do
    x <- die
    y <- die
    return (x, y)

-- Your example
giveRandomElement :: (MonadRandom m) => m Int
giveRandomElement = do
    let n = length tetrominoes
    i <- getRandomR (0, n-1)
    return (giveList !! i)
```

The implementations of this monad will thread the randomness state through your random functions for you. There's even an `instance MonadRandom IO`, which lets you write

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- giveRandomElement
    print x
```